Method for baking Material displacement to mesh
I saw this method (see fb link for video) for creating rocks/cliffs using material displacement but am wondering if there is a way to convert this to a mesh?
From what I've read, it sounds like there is no direct method, but it would be possible if the metaballs in this example were baked to mesh and UV'd?
https://www.facebook.com/watch/?v=1017363692395438

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Instead of using the Displacement node, simply use the Displace modifier and apply the modifier.

Thanks, yes I'm playing with that but it appears to not be as robust? Maybe I'm missing something but the Shader Displacement system allows a node structure to more deeply modify the noise (mixing multiple noises etc), but the Displace Modifier only takes 1 texture. Happy to be corrected on this.

Yes you'll need to bake the b&w map that you've created
